# Displaying a PHP variable inside JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I've spent a big portion of today solving this. But couldn't.

Basically, I want to embed an Youtube video in a PHP page. The `videoid` variable is defined in the PHP page but I cannot make the JS display that variable.

```
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '460',
      width: '760',
      videoId: '<? echo $var;>'
    });
  }
</script>
```

The `$var` variable is present globally within the PHP file but it doesn't work. I also declared a variable within the JS, with no success. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Since it's marked as duplicate, let me explain. I'm not having an issue understanding how to output the PHP variable, it just doesn't work, no matter how I try.

Comment: `var videoid = <?php echo json_encode($phpVariable); ?>;` - or use [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13641184/5827005).

Comment: Why don't you use the PHP and set it to a cookie which you can then access easily in the JS portion of your code

Comment: var videoid = <?php echo json_encode($phpVariable); ?>; doesn't work, when I look in the html source, the file writes the code, not the output.

Comment: Firstly - do you have PHP short tags enabled? Otherwise you'll probably want either `<?php echo $var; ?>` or `<?= $var; ?>` (5.6+). Secondly, what value is *actually* in `$var` at that moment in time? Try putting in something like `alert('<?= $var; ?>');` for debugging.

Comment: Ya, short tags are enabled. If I write alert('<?= $var; ?>'); it outputs the code, not the value. Not sure what's going on. I did a test output outside the <script> tag and the php var outputs correctly.

Comment: The actual value is the video id taken from the database. It outputs correctly if I echo it in the same php file.

Comment: Is your javascript code declared before the php variable? If so, there's your problem.

Comment: No, it's after the declaration. THe site is made with Smarty and the code this code is added in the .tpl file. The variable is declared in a php file which is assigned to that tpl, making it global for that tpl.

Comment: You know you have to use `{php}` tag in smarty if you want to execute php inside the template right? try `videoId: '{php} echo $var; {/php}'` or it might just work if you write `videoId: '{$var}'`

Comment: Ya I know, I tried both, {php} and videoId: '{$var}'. It outputs $var, not the actual value. If I write alert('{php} echo $var; {/php}'); the popup says "{php} echo $var; {/php}"

Comment: Well I guess you have put the script element inside of a smarty `{literal}` tag, that would explain why nothing inside is evaluated, no php, no nothing it's just a literal! :D

Comment: The whole script is wrapped in {literal}, otherwise the page will give an error (there are curly brackets in the function)  :)

Comment: Then I removed the {literal} and added just {ldelim} and {rdelim} instead of the curly brackets. This didn't work either :(

Comment: Yes but you didn't say any of that in your question. Anyway to fix it you have to put the php code outside of the literal, so you can either escape all your `{}` within the script or break the literal for your echo, not pretty but should work: `videoId: '{/literal}{$var}{literal}'`

Comment: wow, that actually worked..wth...You save me a ton. However, I don't understand, I removed the literal and just used {ldelim} and {rdelim} ...why did it took the whole thing literal?

Comment: It should work with `{ldelim}` etc without the `{literal}`, but you still have to use {$var} or `{php} ...` and not `<php ..`. If you did that don't aks me why it didn't work, maybe you have some cached data it's not that easy to answer with an template engine like smarty. I think I write that as an quick answer if your issue is resolved after some digging. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Smarty as your template engine you usually have to put your script code inside a `{literal}` tag, so to execute actualy php code inside your literal tag you have to put the php code outside of the literal, so you can either escape all your `{ }` within the script or break the literal for your echo, not pretty but should work: `videoId: '{/literal}{$var}{literal}'`